# When we click back button from HTC or phone , it doesn't go to login screen

Tags: android

My App screen is goes like (First installation Time Only) License screen 1 -> (First installation Time Only)Database Setup screen 2-  > Splash Screen 3--> Login Screen 4--> Synchronisation screen ---> Main Screen 5.

When I click back button from phone, I doesn't go to previous screen.

In other words,
I have altogether 25 screen there.screen 1 to screen 5 basic setting screen.Screen 5 is main screen.
I am now in Main screen , I clicked back button from phone key ,I won't go to login screen 4 or splash screen 3 or 2 or 1...

but if i am in the screen 10 pressed back key,that time it can go upto screen 5 . cant go first screen 4 or screen 3 or 2 or 1.....

(Main Screen I am using Tab using ActivityGroup. There i used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` .)

Please help me ...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: I am now in Main screen , (That means I have come from screen 1 to screen 5). I clicked back button from phone key ,I won't go to login screen  or splash screen ... How can i do this....

Comment: then where your application will go?any specific screen or just finish the application?

Comment: `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         moveTaskToBack(false);
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }` I did like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start new activity from current activity then don't finish current activity and start new activity so that the previous activity will push on your back-stack.

Ad in main screen you are using Activity-group so there you have a Tab-activity which manages all tab so there you have to override `onBackpressed()` and you have to finish main activity so that the last activity will comes bring to front.

and in Activity group you have to implements this way

```
public class FirstGroup extends ActivityGroup {  

            // Keep this in a static variable to make it accessible for all the nested activities, lets them manipulate the view  
        public static FirstGroup group;  

            // Need to keep track of the history if you want the back-button to work properly, don't use this if your activities requires a lot of memory.  
       private ArrayList<View> history;  

        @Override  
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
              this.history = new ArrayList<View>();  
              group = this;  

                  // Start the root activity withing the group and get its view  
              View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Home", new  
                                                Intent(this,Homepage.class)  
                                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
                                                .getDecorView();  

                  // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup  
              replaceView(view);  

           }  

        public void replaceView(View v) {  
                    // Adds the old one to history  
            history.add(v);  
                    // Changes this Groups View to the new View.  
            setContentView(v);  

        }  

        public void back() {  
            if(history.size() > 0) {  
                history.remove(history.size()-1);  
                if(history.size() > 0) {
                     setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));  
                }
                else {  
                    finish();  
                } 
            }else {  
                finish();  
            }  
        }  

       @Override  
        public void onBackPressed() {  
            FirstGroup.group.back();  
            return;  
        }  

    }
```

Here there is a `back()` method which is used for navigation and will finish() activity group when there are no activity present in its history.

Answer (score 0):

Just call finish after startActivity in every 4 initial screens (Activities)

Comment: that will exit him from the application.Because No activity is available

Comment: That what he whants as I understand it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`..., because thats the one responsible for your problem.. what that flag does is, it closes previous activity once you start new one...

Answer (score 0):

if you are currently in screen no:5 and when user press screen 1 then ::
put `finish();` method in 2md,3rd,4th screen intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          moveTaskToBack(false); return true; 
      } 
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
```

This is way can do....I did like this